# cloud vision api annotate multiple images from a single call

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

For my image processing project, I am using python, cloud vision and cloud storage. In the first link, google explained for single image processing, but I need multiple image processing. I have a folder in cloud storage and I am using that images for processing.

I tried second and the third links but they are old answers and not solved my problem. I think I should create an algorithm for "input_image_uri" like call the function to a for loop. How should I do, I don't know the way.

1- https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#vision_async_batch_annotate_images-python

2- [How to annotate MULTIPLE images from a single call using Google's vision API? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732768/how-to-annotate-multiple-images-from-a-single-call-using-googles-vision-api-py)

3- https://www.py4u.net/discuss/247010

Comment: Is all the images you want to process inside a same folder ?

Comment: Yes all of them in same folder in google storage.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach I use and it works fine for OCR from images. We upload the files in a bucket folder, get the URIS for all images in that folder , prepare a batch request and trigger it. An eg below.

```
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "../my-creds.json" # If you are using service account
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import vision


def file_list(bucket_name, bucket_dir: str):
    # list all files in bucket
    client: storage.Client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=bucket_dir, max_results=200))

    return [f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}" for blob in blob_list]


def prepare_request(file_uris: list):
    # Create the batch request
    requests = []
    # Example feature for OCR
    features = [vision.types.Feature(type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)]

    for image in file_uris:
        source_image = vision.types.ImageSource(image_uri=image)
        request = vision.types.AnnotateImageRequest(image=vision.types.Image(source=source_image),
                                                    features=features)

        requests.append(request)
    return requests


def run_cloud_vision(gcv_credentials=None):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=gcv_credentials)
    src_bucket = ""  # Your bucket name
    src_dir = "test-images/"  # relative path to your directory in bucket. Empty if no dir

    # get file URIs
    file_uris = file_list(src_bucket, src_dir)
    requests = prepare_request(file_uris)

    # trigger a batch annotation request
    response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests)

    # parse your response
    print("parsed response:", response)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_cloud_vision()
```

This might list files other than what you need, if there are other files in the folder / bucket. So you might need to filter the URIS, based on a file pattern may be.

A similar approach will work with other vision APIs as well.

Comment: Thanks for response. Is "src_dir" variable for json data?

Comment: Code didn't work for me. I' m getting this error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with local way with for loop.

```
import os
from google.cloud import vision
import pandas as pd
import io

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '.json key'

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
folder_path = 'main_folder_path'
df_main = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file_name', 'object', 'score'])

for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)):
    path = folder_path + data_file
    # Image_source
    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.Image(content=content)

    response = client.object_localization(image=image)
    localized_object_annotations = response.localized_object_annotations

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file_name', 'object', 'score'])
    for obj in localized_object_annotations:
        df = df.append(
            dict(
                file_name = data_file,
                object = obj.name,
                score = obj.score
            ), ignore_index=True
        )
    df_main = df_main.append(df)
df_main = df_main.to_excel('excel file path')
```